# angular repeat form directive not working editStoryForm is not defined

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-directive

I have a directive that creates a form with a set of inputs. The directive is repeated multiple times on a page. When my `submit` function is triggered, I'm unable to run validations on the form because `editStoryForm` is undefined. How can fix this?

Most of the questions I've found on here deal with validations on repeating form inputs not repeating forms. Additionally, I've tried injecting `$element` into my directive so that I can access my form object that way, as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25771567/4139179) suggests, however when I inject `$element` it is undefined.

Here is my directive:

```
app.directive('story', ['$http', 'modal', function($http, modal) {
    return {
        replace: true,
        templateUrl: '/assets/story.html',
        transclude: false,
        scope: {
            story: '=',
            token: '@'
        },
        controller: ['$scope', '$http', 'modal', function($scope, $http, modal) {
            $scope.editStory = {
                token: $scope.token,
                id: $scope.story.id,
                title: $scope.story.title,
                published: $scope.story.published,
                file: undefined,
                questions_attributes: $scope.story.questions
            };

            $scope.submit = function(result) {
                debugger;
                if (result && $scope.editStoryForm.$valid) {
                    $http.put('/stories/' + result.id + '.json', {
                        workplace_story: result
                    }).progress(function(){
                        $scope.progress = true;
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.progress = false;
                    });
                };
            };
        }]
    }
}]);
```

**Template**

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="editStoryForm" ng-submit="submit(editStory);" multipart="true" novalidate>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-8" style="height: 285px;overflow:hidden;overflow-y:scroll;">
        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" ng-model="editStory.token">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Title</label>
            <input ng-disabled="story.responses.length > 0" type="text" class="form-control" name="title" ng-model="editStory.title" required>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Questions</label>
            <div ng-repeat="q in editStory.questions_attributes">
                <div ng-hide="question._destroy" class="row form-group">
                    <div class="col-lg-10">
                        <input ng-disabled="story.responses.length > 0" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="editStory.questions_attributes[$index]['question']" placeholder="What is the meaning of life, the universe, and everything?"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2">
                        <a ng-if="!story.responses.length > 0" ng-click="removeQuestion($index)" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">X</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$scope.editStoryForm in not define in your controller. if you check your form is valid or not so pass form name in ng-submit method. like:

in Controller:

```
                $scope.submit = function(editStoryForm, result) {
                debugger;
                if (result && editStoryForm.$valid) {
                    $http.put('/stories/' + result.id + '.json', {
                        workplace_story: result
                    }).progress(function(){
                        $scope.progress = true;
                    }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
                        $scope.progress = false;
                    });
                };
            };
```

in HTML :

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="editStoryForm" ng-submit="submit(editStoryForm, editStory);" multipart="true" novalidate>
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Can you explain why I can't access it the way I tried before though? I have other repeatable directives with forms that can be accessed by name like I was trying.